# Unable to Dock "MyComputer" in desktop in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, dock

I was trying to dock "mycomputer" by dragging the "mycomputer" icon to any edge of the screen just as I use to do in Windows XP. But Iam unable to do it .  How is it done in Windows7.

Attached the screen shot taken from my WindowsXP machine.[image]

Comment: That functionality was lost in W7. I miss it too, I did that for my desktop folder, made it a auto hide sidebar. XP was so configurable, W7 is not. Damn I miss XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this app, have not tried it yet, looks promising, not sure if it will work for My Computer but is supposed to work for folders.

http://sourceforge.net/p/sevendeskbar/home/

> A toolbar for Windows© 7 desktop able to restore the old capability to dock a folder and create toolbar from it. No installation, no prerequisites (just .NET Framework 3.5), no admin privileges required just download and run.

Comment: Thanks Moab. +1 for the suggestion. I tried sevendeskbar... I think it not total bug free..My screen flickers once I run the application . Apart from that there is no option to display partitions in the tool bar (as shown in the screen shot.) Once the drive is selected, all folders within the drive are added to the tool bar..

Comment: Yeah, XP can't be beat for being so configurable in so many ways. That was all I could find, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible (natively) in Windows 7. The closest you can get is to right click on the taskbar > Toolbars > New Toolbar then select Computer as the folder.

Answer (score -1):

A fellow wrote "Old Bar" that works and hides, etc only it does not allow a "My Computer" deaskbar, but shortcuts all work:

http://www.ondanera.net/BlogEngine/post/2012/02/09/Its-finally-hiding-itselfOldBar-120.aspx